# Fraction to decimal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I convert a fractional number into decimal number in MATLAB?

I have written some program in MATLAB. But in the iterative process it gives all the number in fraction form but I need all the number in decimal form.

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you using symbolic math?

Comment: Yes. I am using symbolic math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display symbolic variables in numerical format, just call the double function (or any other numerical casting function like int) on them. For example,

```
syms x;
% ...
double(x)
```

Note that if your variable is a symbolic expression, using double won't work. In such situation, you could use the vpa function to approximate it:

```
syms x;
y = (log(3) * x) + 1;
vpa(y)
```